# Is there a storage capacity limit for external hard-drive enclosures?

Tags: external-hard-drive, sata

I'm looking to purchase a 2TB SATA hard-drive, and I want to get an external e-sata enclosure for it. When looking for possible enclosures I have noticed maximum storage limits for them (eg 750G, 1.5TB etc).

Is there really a size limitation for a basic enclosure, or is it simply that the manufacturers are simply protecting themselves with the largest size drives they happen to have tested with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really, no, the specification were probably written at a time when 1 or 1.5 TB was the maximum available size for consumer hard drives, 2 TB HDDs only became mainstream very recently.

i recently replaced 2 original 500 GB drives with 2 TB drives in 2-year old Toshiba enclosures, no problem.

Comment: Have encounterd an issue where the power supply would not power a newer drivve.   Did not seem to the size per se.  Maker was Macally and they offered a new power supply (at about the cost of a new enclosure)